# Select the last element using id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a load-more function using jquery. With my current approach I only load more content after the last `question-summay` which appears in the last tab pan of my table. I want, when I click on my load-more button to load my content after the last `question-summary` of that `question-col` with the respective id.

My JS function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".loadMore").on('click', function () {
        var tab = $(this).data('tab');
        var next_page = $(this).data('next-page');
        console.log(next_page);
        console.log(tab);
        $.get($(this).data('url') + '?tab=' + tab + '&page=' + next_page, function (data) {
            addNewQuestions($.parseJSON(data), tab);
        });
        $(this).data('next-page', parseInt(next_page) + 1);
    });

    siteStats();
});

function addNewQuestions(objects, tab) {

    $.each(objects, function (i, object) {
        console.log(tab);
        var lastItem = $(".question-summary:last");
        console.dir(lastItem);
        var newLine = lastItem.clone(true);

        var newObject = newLine.find('.question-info');

        updateTitleAndLink(newObject.find('.summary a'), object);
        updateCreationDate(newObject.find('.question-updated-at'), object);
        updateQuestionAnswers(newObject.find('.question-answers'), object);
        updateAnswerCount(newObject.find('.answers-count'), object);
        updateViewsCount(newObject.find('.views-count'), object);
        updateVotesCount(newObject.find('.votes-count'), object);
        updateSolvedStatus(newObject.find('.status'), object)

        lastItem.after(newLine);
    });
}
```

I believe the problem is on the line `var lastItem = $("question-summary:last");`. I tried a lot of different solutions, like `.question-col#tab.question-summary` to select the correct element with id tab but that did not work.

```
<div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#recent_questions">Recent Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unanswered_questions">Unanswered Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#top">Top Scored Questions</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="recent_questions" class="question-col">
        <div class="question-summary narrow">

            <div class="question-info col-md-12">

                <div class="votes">
                    <div class="votes-count">
                <span title="{$question['votes_count']} votes">
                    {if $question['votes_count']}
                        {$question['votes_count']}
                    {else}
                        0
                    {/if}
                </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>votes</div>
                </div>

                <div {if $question['solved_date']}
                    class="status answered-accepted"
                {else}
                    class="status answer-selected"
                {/if}
                        title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
                    <div class="answers-count">
                        <span title="{$question['answers_count']} answer">{$question['answers_count']}</span></div>
                    <div>answer</div>
                </div>
                <div class="views">
                    <div class="views-count">
                        <span title="{$question['views_counter']} views">{$question['views_counter']}</span></div>
                    <div>views</div>
                </div>

                <div class="summary question-title">
                    <h3>
                        <a href="{questionUrl($question['publicationid'])}"
                           data-base-question-url = "{questionUrl('')}"
                           style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.4; margin-bottom: .5em;">
                            {$question['title']}
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div>


                <div class = "statistics col-sm-12 text-right" style="padding-top: 8px">
            <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                <span class="question-updated-at">{$question['creation_date']}</span>
            </span>
                    <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
                <span class="question-answers">{$question['answers_count']}</span>
            </span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class = "loadMore"
             data-next-page = "1"
             data-url = "{url('controller/api/questions/load_more_questions')}"
             data-tab = "recent_questions">
            <a style="color: #f9f9f9">
                Load More...
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="unanswered_questions" class="question-col">
        {foreach $unanswered_questions as $question}
            <div class="question-summary narrow">

                <div class="question-info col-md-12">

                    <div class="votes">
                        <div class="votes-count">
                <span title="{$question['votes_count']} votes">
                    {if $question['votes_count']}
                        {$question['votes_count']}
                    {else}
                        0
                    {/if}
                    </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>votes</div>
                    </div>

                    <div {if $question['solved_date']}
                        class="status answered-accepted"
                    {else}
                        class="status answer-selected"
                    {/if}
                            title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
                        <div class="answers-count">
                            <span title="{$question['answers_count']} answer">{$question['answers_count']}</span></div>
                        <div>answer</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="views">
                        <div class="views-count">
                            <span title="{$question['views_counter']} views">{$question['views_counter']}</span></div>
                        <div>views</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="summary question-title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="{questionUrl($question['publicationid'])}"
                               data-base-question-url = "{questionUrl('')}"
                               style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.4; margin-bottom: .5em;">
                                {$question['title']}
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>


                    <div class = "statistics col-sm-12 text-right" style="padding-top: 8px">
            <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                <span class="question-updated-at">{$question['creation_date']}</span>
            </span>
                        <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
                <span class="question-answers">{$question['answers_count']}</span>
            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        {/foreach}

        <div class = "loadMore"
             data-next-page = "1"
             data-url = "{url('controller/api/questions/load_more_questions')}"
             data-tab = "unanswered_questions">
            <a style="color: #f9f9f9">
                Load More...
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="top" class="question-col">
        {foreach $top_scored_questions as $question}
            <div class="question-summary narrow">

                <div class="question-info col-md-12">

                    <div class="votes">
                        <div class="votes-count">
                <span title="{$question['votes_count']} votes">
                    {if $question['votes_count']}
                        {$question['votes_count']}
                    {else}
                        0
                    {/if}
                    </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>votes</div>
                    </div>

                    <div {if $question['solved_date']}
                        class="status answered-accepted"
                    {else}
                        class="status answer-selected"
                    {/if}
                            title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
                        <div class="answers-count">
                            <span title="{$question['answers_count']} answer">{$question['answers_count']}</span></div>
                        <div>answer</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="views">
                        <div class="views-count">
                            <span title="{$question['views_counter']} views">{$question['views_counter']}</span></div>
                        <div>views</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="summary question-title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="{questionUrl($question['publicationid'])}"
                               data-base-question-url = "{questionUrl('')}"
                               style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.4; margin-bottom: .5em;">
                                {$question['title']}
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>


                    <div class = "statistics col-sm-12 text-right" style="padding-top: 8px">
            <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                <span class="question-updated-at">{$question['creation_date']}</span>
            </span>
                        <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
                <span class="question-answers">{$question['answers_count']}</span>
            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        {/foreach}

        <div class = "loadMore"
             data-next-page = "1"
             data-url = "{url('controller/api/questions/load_more_questions')}"
             data-tab = "top_scored_questions">
            <a style="color: #f9f9f9">
                Load More...
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: to select last you can use `.last()`

Comment: I want to select the last of a specific element, in this case `question-col`. I don't think you even read the question.

Comment: `$(".question-summary").last();`

Comment: `last()` or `:last` is exactly what you need. There's no need to be so abrasive to someone who's attempting to help you. Either way, this question should be closed as a basic typo

Comment: you are missing `.` from your selector `var lastItem = $("question-summary:last");`  add `.` since it is class

Comment: It wasn't my intention to be abrasive, really. But the `:last` is already there and it is exactly the problem I am reporting. I'm saying that I want to select the last of `question-col` no the last `question-summary` at all.
I'm sorry If I sounded condescendent. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the class (dot) selector:

```
var lastItem = $("question-summary:last");
```

Try this:

```
var numQ = $('.question-summary').length;
var lastItem = $('.question-summary').eq(numQ-1);
```

Comment: I was about to edit. I fixed it. That isn't the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

To select last you can use `.last()` with class selector like

```js
alert($('.myList').last().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myList">One</li>
  <li class="myList">Two</li>
  <li class="myList">Three</li>
</ul>
```